# Restrict access to parts of admin pages

Tags: users

I've setup a site for a client I want them to have access to edit content, but some of the permissions grant too much control for my liking. Can someone give me a way to be a bit more selective with permissions. These are my areas of interest.

1. I have a custom block which contains 2 editable fields, To allow access I have to grant access to Administer Blocks, which give the user access to reposition the block, I would like this to disabled, and also the Regional and Visability settings to be disabled.
2. When editing a Basic Page node, I have an image field which I dont want the user to be able to adjust.

Any clever people out there know the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add the "[#access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#access)" property to the form fields you don't want to be accessible from the user.
Normally you should use code similar to the following one, but every function that returns `FALSE` when the current logged-in user should not access the form field would work too.

```
$form['form_field']['#access'] = user_access("access form_field");
```

The permission the code checks can be any of the permissions the module implements, or other modules implement.

Comment: Thank you, that does seem the most likely solution. Would you know where I can locate the specific form_field values for these areas I'm interested in? This always seems to be the area I get stuck on.

Comment: You need to look at the source code of the module for that: Knowing the path of the page you are watching, you can know which module is showing that page by looking at all the `hook_menu()` implementations of the enabled modules; from that, you can know which function is outputting the form, and where the function is located.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I looked though the modules and found pretty much everything I needed. I did have trouble with some areas,  but I guess I still need more experience with Drupal.